# How can I estimate the elasto-optic coefficients ($p_{11}$ and $p_{12}$) of a material?

Tags: optics, refraction

I am attempting to estimate the elasto-optic coefficients ($p_{11}$ and $p_{12}$) of $\mathrm{TiO}_2$ and $\mathrm{ZrO}_2$, where $p_{11}$ and $p_{12}$ refer to the elements of a strain-optic tensor for a homogeneous material as given in Hocker (Fiber-optic sensing of pressure and temperature, 1979).

I have [found a document](http://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/Publications/SBSreview.pdf) which specifies that the longitudinal elasto-optic coefficient ($p_{12}$) can be estimated using the Lorentz-Lorenz relation that it gives as

$$p_{12} = \frac{(n^2 - 1)(n^2 + 2)}{3n^4}$$

however no reference is given, and other sources give the Lorentz-Lorenz relation as something rather different. For example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Lorenz_equation) says that the equation relates the refractive index of a substance to its polarizability and gives it as

$$\frac{n^2 - 1}{n^2 + 2} = \frac{4\pi}{3}N\alpha$$

which bares only a vague relation to the earlier equation.

Does anyone know of any other ways in which to estimate the elasto-optic coefficients of a material?

Comment: Excellent question! Unfortunately I don't know much of anything about optics but I'll see if I can draw some attention to this.

Comment: Thanks - hopefully some insight will be forthcoming soon :)

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I'm wondering the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh, I tried looking through various books (like Korpel's Acousto-Optics") but it seems like it's not going to be straightforward to find out. Maybe you could try emailing Carl Mungan at http://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/index.php and ask him where he got the formula from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasto-optic properties are complex tensorial properties, and I don't think there is any *good* way to estimate them short of:

- measuring them experimentally
- calculating them through quantum chemistry methods ([CRYSTAL14](http://www.crystal.unito.it/index.php) is one code with such features)
- finding them in the literature

---

Luckily for you, a simple search reveals that values have been measured, at least for TiO<sub>2</sub>:

[image]

[Source here](http://photonics.intec.ugent.be/education/IVPV/res_handbook/v2ch12.pdf); it's Google's first hit for a search of “elasto-optic tensor TiO2”.

Comment: Nice :-) I'm not sure if the OP is still around to accept the answer but this does seem to cover it!

Answer (score 0):

Boyd is a useful reference. See for example:

E.L. Buckland and R.W. Boyd, "Electrostrictive contribution to the intensity-dependent refractive index of optical fibers," Opt. Lett. 21:1117 (1 Aug. 1996)

where the dielectric constant epsilon is the square of the refractive index n.

Comment: Only mentioning a reference might not help people who do not have that book, since this is an equivalent or maybe even worse as a [link only answer](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/859/are-link-only-answers-acceptable). Could you summarize the relevant section of your mentioned reference?